# Order of MappedInterceptor in Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have this config...

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Jsr310JpaConverters.class, MyEntity.class})
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor correlationIdMappedInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[] {"/**"}, new CorrelationIdInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor loggingMappedInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[] {"/**"}, new LoggingInterceptor());
    }

    // More config...
}
```

... and I want to ensure `correlationIdMappedInterceptor` is always executed **before** `loggingMappedInterceptor`.

I have some `@RestController`s **AND** `@RepositoryRestResource`s (or `CrudRepository`), and I want my interceptors to work on both. I tried overriding:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new MappedInterceptor(new String[] {"/**"}, new CorrelationIdInterceptor()));
    registry.addInterceptor(new MappedInterceptor(new String[] {"/**"}, new LoggingInterceptor()));
}
```

which does the job, but only works for `@RestController`.

I tried `@Order`, which does absolutely nothing in this case.

I tried `@DependsOn()`, which seems to successfully control the order used to inject my `@Bean`s, but it seems that no matter the order my beans are injected using this strategy, my interceptors are getting called in the same order.

The only way I've found so far, is the order my factory methods appears in my config class. In fact, everything's currently working as it is. But this is ugly, I can't be sure noone in my project will ever change the order of methods in the config... I don't wanna rely on this. This is kinda weird.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could make a custom (Abstract)HandlerMapping, which you can give a execution order (setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)), so it is executed first. Then create an Interceptor only executed by this (Abstract)HandlerMapping.